# iOS open locally saved file in Microsoft Word or PowerPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ms-word, ms-office

I need to open a locally saved file in my documents directory in Microsoft Word for doc files or PowerPoint for ppt files.

I've used the UIDocumentInteractionController which works to open these documents, problem is that the client doesn't want to show all the options to open the document and restrict it just to Word or PowerPoint.

```
self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:attachmentURL];
```

So then I used the UIActivityViewController to restrict the options, but without even using UIActivityViewController.excludedActivityTypes the Microsoft options no longer appear using the same NSURL.

```
self.activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[attachmentURL] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Not sure what I'm missing? Or is it possible to open the documents without using either of these classes?

Comment: As far as I know the only way to restrict the "open in" menu is through the use of managed apps controlled via an MDM.

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm currently showing the documents in a uiwebview, but the client wants the documents shared specifically with their installed Microsoft Word and PowerPoint apps